# I want to store my timepicker value of react in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to store the timepicker value in tmy firestore databse but i am unable to understand how to do so.

code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TimePicker from 'react-time-picker';

function MyApp() {
const [value, onChange] = useState('10:00');

return (
<div>
  <TimePicker onChange={onChange} value={value} />
</div>
);
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, Mister, sometimes, when I use new library, such as your time-picker, I don't know anything about it. So, I use `console.log()` to know its value. In your case, you can try

```
<TimePicker onChange={value=> console.log(value)}/>
```

After that, you can store the value to firestore. Firestore can accept 'timestamp' or 'text'. Choose your data format.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I am new to react can you if possible share the entire code of how to store in react or share a guide.

Comment: There are a lot of guides for react. I started reading their official document, then learnt some usages that I don't understand from other articles. https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html